# SQL count sum optimized query

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, count, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(subbrandcount) AS Totalsubbrand ,
       SUM(stylecode) AS Reference
FROM
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(subbrand)) AS subbrandcount,
             COUNT(DISTINCT(t_product_flat.reference)) AS stylecode
        FROM smiddleware.t_warehouseinventory
  INNER JOIN catalog.t_product_flat 
          ON t_warehouseinventory.a_productcode=t_product_flat.ean13
       WHERE a_quantity > 0
    GROUP BY t_product_flat.Subbrand) subbrandtable
```

This query is giving me the desired result but I still need to optimize it, because it's increasing my page load time.

My page has 20 sql queries but everything is a subquery so it takes more time to render the page.

The below picture shows the query explanation.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `EXPLAIN` to get the execution plan of this query? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: yes i added the explain.see the picture.

Comment: In the explain I see that MySQL is not using any indexes on `t_warehaouseinventory`. Could you add an index on `t_warehouseinventory.a_productcode` and retry the query? (and the `EXPLAIN`)

Comment: From the query plan it looks like most of the records in `t_warehouseinventory` have a `a_quantity > 0`. If that is the case, your only option is to pre-calculate and cache the counts.